# Intuition behind storing sum and frequency in the HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

We have been given an array of integers and another number `k` and we need to find the total number of continuous subarrays whose sum equals to `k`.  I found the following interesting code snippet on LeetCode:

```
public class Solution {
    public int subarraySum(int[] nums, int k) {
        int count = 0, sum = 0;
        HashMap < Integer, Integer > map = new HashMap < > ();
        map.put(0, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum += nums[i];
            if (map.containsKey(sum - k))
                count += map.get(sum - k);
            map.put(sum, map.getOrDefault(sum, 0) + 1);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

I liked the efficient solution and so I am trying to understand it; however I have two questions:

1. What is the intuition behind storing the current `sum` and its `frequency` in the HashMap?
2. What is the guarantee that the subarray that we detect is continuous?

Sample input: `[1,1,1]` and k=`2`;
Output: `2`

Comment: Update - the question is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/description/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice algorithm.

Lets start from simple fact: `sum(1, i) = sum(1, j) + sum(j + 1, i)` (I don't use Java here it is usual math notation)
It is true for any `i` and `j`.

We need to find all `sum(j+1, i)` equals to `k`.

It is same that find `sum(1, i) = sum(1, j) + k` or `sum(1, i) -k = sum(1, j)`

In your program `sum(1, i)` is `sum` variable. So we need to check do we have any `j` for which `sum -k = sum(1, j)` is true. Hopefully we have all `sum(1, j)` as keys in our `map`.

We check `map.containsKey(sum - k)` and if it is true then there is such `j` that give us required sum.

Values in map are needed to count how many different way to get such sum.

PS: BTW if all values are non-negative there is better algorithm. it doesn't require extra memory.

PPS: Also I made some improvement to your code in case you in Java 8

```
    for (int num : nums) {
        sum += num;
        count += map.getOrDefault(sum - k, 0);
        map.compute(sum, (key, value) -> (value == null) ? 1 : value + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain why we use `sum` as the key in the map; but then query it using `sum-k`?

Comment: I tried to restate my answer. But It would be easier with pen and paper. But I'm too lazy to draw in paint.

Comment: Maybe you can do with a pen and paper and then upload your calculations as an image?  You can update your answer later.  I'm not sure if this would be as per SO policies though.

Comment: I restated my answer again. Hope that brings som light to where `sum - k` came from.

Comment: I asked a follow-up to this question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63653036/8305079).

Answer (score 3):

As we scanning the `nums[]` array, `map` will contain how many times we've seen a particular `sum` (`sum` means summing the numbers from the beginning to the current point).

Now, at any given point, at `if`, if we see, that the `map` contains `sum-k` X times, and the current sum is `sum`, we know, that we found X different subarrays with the sum `k`. It is because `sum` contains sum from the beginning to the current point, and `map` is indexed by sum-from-the-beginning-to-a-certain-point. If `map` contains a value of greater than one, it means that a certain sum happens multiple times (it can happen, if `num[]` has zero or negative numbers). The found subarray is from this from this "certain" point to our current position, so it must be continuous.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate - _if we see, that the map contains `sum-k` X times, and the current sum is `sum`, we know, that we found X different subarrays with the sum `k`_.  In my opinion, if we see that the map contains sum X times, and the current sum is again `sum` then we can say that we found X+1 different subarrays with the sum `sum`.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela: it is "map contains **`sum-k`** X times", and `sum-(sum-k)=k`

Comment: How did you get `sum-(sum-k)`?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela: it means, that currently, our sum is `sum`. We're searching for subarray sum `k`. So, we need to check the `map` for sum `sum-k`, because if we subtract `sum-k` from  our current `sum`, we'll get `k`, the amount we searching for

Comment: But we aren't subtracting, are we?  Sorry, I am finding it a bit difficult to understand.  I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela: what do you mean by that? Suppose, that our current sum is 12. Now, if we find, how many ways (let's call it X) we already seen the sum 10, then we know, that we had X ways to express the difference, `12-10`=2, the number we're searching for.

Comment: Thank you.  This example makes it a bit easier for me to understand.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela: Great :) I you still not understand exactly, I recommend you to try the algorithm on a simple example, with positive only numbers. This way `map` only will contain ones, so it might be easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you.  I wish I could accept your answer as well, rather than just an upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

3 key things:

- first key is a 0
- increase `count` only if a key `sum - k` is already in a map
- put to map each sum with it's frequency

I will divide it into 3 cases:

**1st: Numbers greater than zero**.

Each key will have frequency equal 1.
So how count increased? It can increase only if key already was in a map.
Keys are all previous sums. So current key for condition `if (map.containsKey(sum - k))` is `sum - k`. If `sum - k` is a key, it means that between previous sum (`sum - k`) and current sum are elements for which sum was equal `k` (cause `k + (sum - k) = sum` - our current value). So we can increase `count` - we've found sub array.

**2nd: Numbers greater or equal zero.**
So now we could put zeros in between. It doesn't differ much, but you can imagine what would happen if we increased `count` and in the next step we will have 0 in our `nums` array.
In this case we will increase our `count` again normally.

With zero included our frequency will change. Imagine this example:
`subarraySum({0, 0, 0, 7, 0}, 7);` the result is 8.
Remember that first key is a 0. So when we iterating, and we are at 7, we've got a map `(0: 4)`. Now `sum = 7` and `7 - 7  = 0`, so, we've got 3, so this time count increased by this frequency. Now we are picking last element from array - 0. Value for this key is still 4. `sum - k` is still the same, so again our `count` increased by 4.

**3rd: Integers**.
I think you get the point ;) This time negative numbers might increase some frequency also.
If we had key `sum - key` in a map, then it means that between previous sum (`sum - k`) and now we had integers, which summed to `k` (cause `k + (sum - k) = sum` - our current value). If so, let's increase count by frequency.

Comment: You say _So current key is `sum - k`_.  How?  Isn't it just `sum`?

Comment: `sum` is `sum`, we are using here: `if (map.containsKey(sum - k))` key `sum - k`.

Comment: So my precise question is: if we are using `sum` as the key in the map during insertion, then why do we use `sum-k` as the key while looking up?

Comment: Let's assume, we have 1st case. This way we are at some point of iteration. Now we know that each key has frequency 1. Do you see this?

Comment: We are using sum to insert before we are doing lookup. We are using key `sum - k` to check if we had this sum `sum - k` previously.