# Can we really avoid extra space when all the values are non-negative?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, space-complexity

This question is a follow-up of [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45102468/8305079) I had asked quite a while ago:

> We have been given an array of integers and another number k and we need to find the total number of continuous subarrays whose sum equals to k.  For e.g., for the input: `[1,1,1]` and `k=2`, the expected output is `2`.

In the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103345/8305079), [@talex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656904/talex) says:

> PS: BTW if all values are non-negative there is better algorithm. it doesn't require extra memory.

While I didn't think much about it then, I am curious about it now.  IMHO, we *will* require extra memory.  In the event that all the input values are non-negative, our running (prefix) sum will go on increasing, and as such, sure, we don't need an `unordered_map` to store the frequency of a particular sum.  But, we will still need extra memory (perhaps an `unordered_set`) to store the running (prefix) sums that we get along the way.  This obviously contradicts what [@talex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656904/talex) said.

Could someone please confirm if we absolutely *do* need extra memory or if it could be avoided?

Thanks!

Comment: I recall having seen this problem before, so this must be a duplicate. Can somebody find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a slightly simpler problem: all values are positive (no zeros). In this case the sub arrays can overlap, but they cannot contain one another.

I.e.: arr = `2 1 5 1 1 5 1 2`, Sum = `8`

```
2 1 5 1 1 5 1 2
|---|
  |-----|
      |-----|
          |---|
```

But this situation can never occur:

```
* * * * * * *
  |-------|
    |---|
```

With this in mind there is algorithm that doesn't require extra space (well.. `O(1)` space) and has `O(n)` time complexity. The ideea is to have left and right indexes indicating the current sequence and the sum of the current sequence.

- if the sum is `k` increment the counter, advance `left` and `right`
- if the sum is less than `k` then advance `right`
- else advance `left`

---

Now if there are zeros the intervals can contain one another, but only if the zeros are on the margins of the interval.

To adapt to non-negative numbers:

Do as above, except:

- skip zeros when advancing `left`
- if sum is `k`:

  - count consecutive zeros to the right of `right`, lets say `zeroes_right_count`
  - count consecutive zeros to the left of `left`. lets say `zeroes_left_count`
  - instead of incrementing the count as before, increase the counter by: `(zeroes_left_count + 1) * (zeroes_right_count + 1)`

Example:

```
... 7 0 0 5  1  2 0 0 0 9 ...
          ^     ^
          left  right
```

Here we have 2 zeroes to the left and 3 zeros to the right. This makes `(2 + 1) * (3 + 1) = 12` sequences with sum `8` here:

```
5 1 2
5 1 2 0
5 1 2 0 0 
5 1 2 0 0 0

0 5 1 2 
0 5 1 2 0
0 5 1 2 0 0 
0 5 1 2 0 0 0

0 0 5 1 2
0 0 5 1 2 0
0 0 5 1 2 0 0 
0 0 5 1 2 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this algorithm would work, using `O(1)` space.

We maintain two pointers to the beginning and end of the current subsequence, as well as the sum of the current subsequence. Initially, both pointers point to `array[0]`, and the sum is obviously set to `array[0]`.

Advance the end pointer (thus extending the subsequence to the right), and increase the sum by the value it points to, until that sum exceeds `k`. Then advance the start pointer (thus shrinking the subsequence from the left), and decrease the sum, until that sum gets below `k`. Keep doing this until the end pointer reaches the end of the array. Keep track of the number of times the sum was exactly `k`.

Comment: Since the values are merely nonnegative, not strictly positive, you need to account for zeros.

Comment: @EricPostpischil We leave this as an exercise for the reader. It is reasonably straightforward to adapt the approach to handle that.